# Discord.js changing channel permissions does nothing

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I recently started working on a discord.js bot, and I came across a very weird issue, that I couldn't fix, or figure out what to do. I wanted to create a voice channel with custom permissions, so I used this function (or I don't know what its called I'm new to js):

```
message.guild.channels.create(`Room of ${message.member.displayName}`, {type: 'voice'}, {
    permissionOverwrites: [{ 
        id: message.guild.defaultRole, 
        allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL'
    }]
});
```

I noticed this: If I place the `{type: 'voice'}` before the `permissionOverwrites`, it works normally (except the permissions don't work at all), but if I place it after the `permissionOverwrites` the permissions work normally, but the type won't work.

I get no console error, or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [discord.js docs for channel creation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create), the method `create()` takes only two arguments: The *channel name* and the *channel options*. 
Which means you have to put all your options into a single object:

```js
message.guild.channels.create(`Room of ${message.member.displayName}`, {
    type: 'voice',
    permissionOverwrites: [{ 
        id: message.guild.defaultRole, 
        allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL'
    }]
});
```

So the reason for the behavior you encountered is simply that your third argument for `create()` is completely ignored, no matter what you put there.

Comment: Yes! Thanks you so much!